# Using lmer for full HLM with multiple level 1 variables---syntax question

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I know there are several questions on specifying random effects with lmer. I looked at perhaps 20 of them, and they all seemed to be basic questions or questions about nesting in 3-level structures.

I need to know how the proper syntax for a full HLM model that uses multiple level 1 variables. By "full HLM" I just mean that every level 2 equation will includes a random effect and every level 2 variable influences the coefficient for every level 1 variable.

I have used these two sources to convert HLM structures to the generic multilevel/mixed-modeling provided by lme4:

[source 1](http://faculty.smu.edu/kyler/training/aera_overheads.pdf)
[source 2, using nlme but showing same basic idea](https://www.methodsconsultants.com/tutorial/estimating-hlm-models-using-r-part-1/)

Assume there is one level 2 variable Z and two level-1 variables A and B. Say the output is Y and the grouping variable is G.

Which of the following is the correct specification of the full HLM model:

```
myModel<- lmer(Y~Z*(A+B) + (A + B |G))
```

or

```
myModel<- lmer(Y~Z(A+B) + (A|G) + (B|G))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a source that explicitly addresses this case.

According to [this document from the University of Freibourgh](https://moodle2.unifr.ch/pluginfile.php/374077/mod_resource/content/0/hlm_comparison.pdf) the correct syntax is the one with a single term (A + B |G).